# Terminology for a "futuristic" interface, objects, etc.

Tags: terminology, style-identification

So I am making a program which uses a "futureistic" graphical interface. My problem is that though i have seen examples of it in the past, i cannot think of what to call it when searching through google for refrences.

An example would be a semi-transparent circle with semi-transparent "C"'s rotating around it but intersecting with it. The circle would be the top layer with the rest below it. The image would always be in motion.

I would like to know what it is called. Sorry if I confused anyone, im slightly confused as to how to explain this. Ask me questions so that I can explain anything.

Comment: Can you give some examples where you've seen it? Your description made me think of R2-D2 interfacing on the Death Star, and hearing "futuristic interface" makes me think of Iron Man or Minority Report.

Comment: Radial UI, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for are User Interfaces(UI). Futuristic is the type of style that you would like the UI to be in. There are plenty of websites with tons of UI resources for inspiration or for you to use.

Here are two links to get you started:

http://www.uiparade.com/

http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/inspiration/exploring-graphic-user-interface-styles-from-minimal-to-futuristic/

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I think in general Futuristic might work but Futurists and Futurist Artists are not at all what the asker is looking for. Some might call it that anyways but it would be uncommon as "Futurism" comes from facist Italy.

You should try looking for "Techno Designs" or "High Tech Interfaces" and that should start you off in the right direction.

Comment: +1. one link to definition of Futurism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurism

Answer (score 0):

People who study trends and try and make reasonable predictions regarding technology are often called **Futurists**, and designers are often called **Futurist Artists**. Start there.

Comment: But futurists typically try to analyze technological, cultural, and social trends to extrapolate where humanity/technology is headed in the future. What the questioner describes sounds like pointless visualization that is strictly there as superficial decoration. It's sorta like how old sci-fi films have walls or workstations covered with rows and rows flashing lights, illuminated buttons and toggle switches--totally unusable/impractical and just looks pretty silly to us these days, but back then it looked "futuristic".